# gulp - merge 2 folders, choose action for file having same name

Tags: gulp

I need to copy the content of 2 folders in an another folder.
If there are files having same name, and depending on the file extension, a function is executed:
- concat : JS, LESS ...
- merge : json
- overwrite : images, HTML ...

To copy the 2 folders is not the problem, it's the second part :(

```
var route = 'bower_components/any-folder';
gulp.task('test', function() {
    return gulp.src([route + '**/*', 'source/**/*', route + '!bower_components{,/**}', route + '!node_modules{,/**}'])
        .pipe( $.replace( '@@_APP_@@', 'myApp' ) )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp'));
});
```

Can someone can provide any help please.

**EDIT :** A diagram of my infrastructure that I would

```
|-gulpfile.js
|-bower_components
|   |-module
|   |   |-bower.json
|   |   |-package.json
|   |   |-index.less
|   |   |-hello.png
|-source
|   |-bower.json
|   |-package.json
|   |-index.less
|   |-hello.png
```

This is what I want :

```
|-public
|   |-bower.json (merge between bower_components/module & source)
|   |-package.json (merge between bower_components/module & source)
|   |-index.less (concat between bower_components/module & source)
|   |-hello.png (provide from source, overwrite the copy from bower_components/module)
```

Comment: I would write separate tasks for each of the required functions - one for concat, one for merge, one for overwrite. Then specify the qualifying file extensions in the gulp.src

Comment: I agree to separate into different tasks.
But my problem is that if I move a file in a folder that already has a file with the same name, I wish to concatenate, merge, overwrite..., but if the files have different names, then just move it. For basic, move a file in a folder that already has a file with the same name, it overwrites.

Answer (score 1):

The case where you want to overwrite the files is the simplest, as gulp.dest overwrites by default, and gulp.src processes the specified files in order. You want the file from source to be used in preference to the one in bower_components.  So something like this should work

```
gulp.task('overwrite', () => {
  gulp.src('./bower_components/**/*.png', './source/**/*.png')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./temp'));
});
```

So if the file exists in both locations, the one from source will overwrite the one from bower_components in ./temp.

Give that a try for a start

Comment: to overwrite files, your code is OK. It's for the other case I'm stuck :\

Comment: Well based on the above you should be able to make a good guess at it. If you use gulp-concat for concatenating and merge-stream for merging you should be able to manage it OK.

Comment: Yes, but I want to concat or combine file only if the file already exist. If the file does not exist, I just want to move it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an arbitrary solution to this, I came up with the following transform stream (implemented using [through2](https://github.com/rvagg/through2)) for grouping files based on an arbitrary key:

```
function groupFiles(
    keyFunc = file => file.relative,
    newFunc = newConcatFile,
    mergeFunc = appendConcatFile,
    flushFunc = flushConcatFile) {
  const groups = {}
  return through2.obj(
    function (file, _encoding, callback) {
      const key = keyFunc(file)
      let chunk
      let state = groups[key]
      if (state === undefined) {
        ({ chunk, state } = newFunc(key, file))
      } else {
        ({ chunk, state } = mergeFunc(key, file, state))
      }
      groups[key] = state
      callback(null, chunk)
    },
    function (callback) {
      const keys = Object.keys(groups)
      keys.forEach(key => {
        const state = groups[key]
        flushFunc(key, state, this)
      })
      callback()
    })
}
```

By default, it will concatenate files based on the relative path:

```
function newConcatFile(key, file) {
  const chunk = file.clone({ contents: false })
  const state = new ConcatSource({}, file.contents)
  chunk.contents = state
  return { chunk, state }
}

function appendConcatFile(key, file, state) {
  state.addSource(file.contents)
  return { chunk: null, state }
}

function flushConcatFile(key, state) {
  state.end()
}
```

`ConcatSource` is a [`Readable`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_readable_stream) stream that can have buffers, strings, or streams appended to it:

```
class ConcatSource extends Readable {
  constructor(options, sources) {
    super(options)
    this._sources = Array.isArray(sources) ? sources : sources != null ? [sources] : []
    this._currentSource = null
    this._readPending = false
    this._noMoreSources = false
  }
  _read(size) {
    for (;;) {
      let source = this._currentSource
      if (source == null) {
        if (this._sources.length > 0) {
          source = this._currentSource = this._sources.shift()
        } else if (this._noMoreSources) {
          this.push(null)
          break
        } else {
          this._readPending = size || true
          break
        }
      }
      let data
      if (Buffer.isBuffer(source) || typeof source === 'string') {
        data = source
        this._currentSource = null
      } else {
        data = source.read(size)
        if (data == null) {
          this._currentSource = null
          continue
        }
      }
      if (!this.push(data)) {
        break
      }
    }
  }
  addSource(source) {
    if (this._noMoreSources) {
      this.emit('error', new Error('end() has been called'))
    } else if (source) {
      this._sources.push(source)
      if (this._readPending) {
        this._read(this._readPending !== true ? this._readPending : undefined)
      }
    }
  }
  end() {
    this._noMoreSources = true
    if (this._readPending) {
      this.push(null)
      this._readPending = false
    }
  }
}
```